# Ansible looping over main playbook

Tags: ansible

I created a "main" playbook that create and deploy a complex application let's say an entire house.

The "main" looks like this :

```
- hosts: host1
  roles:
    - { role: role1 }

- hosts: host2
  roles:
    - { role: role2 }

- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - { role: role3 }
    - { role: role4 }
    - { role: role5 }
    - { role: role6 }
```

I would like now to be able to deploy multiple houses using a CSV as input, containing my variables.

I was expecting to just import that "main" playbook, and loop over my CSV so that I can create multiple houses.

Based on the documentation I'm not able to loop using `import_playbook`, so I'm a stuck on how I could use this "main" for multiple creations in series.

Has anybody been in that situation or has an idea on how I could resolve this ?

Comment: Launch the playbook several times in a script else review your entire playbook architecture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`csvfile`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/csvfile_lookup.html) lookup to read data from CSV files.

Example CSV file `roles.csv`:

```
host1,role1
host2,role2
localhost,role3 role4 role5 role6
```

Create mock-up roles:

```sh
for i in {1,2,3,4,5,6}; do
  mkdir -p roles/role$i/tasks &&
  echo "- debug: msg=\"role$i\"" > roles/role$i/tasks/main.yaml
done
```

And in the playbook you use the [`include_role`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html) syntax instead of `roles`, because `include_role` can be used in a loop. By this you can loop over the array read from the CSV file.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Use role in loop
      include_role:
        name: '{{ roleinputvar }}'
      loop: "{{ lookup('csvfile', inventory_hostname + ' file=roles.csv delimiter=,').split(' ') }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: roleinputvar
```

`connection: local` is just for this example.

When run the roles 3 to 6 are executed:

```
$ ansible-playbook roles.yaml 
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the
implicit localhost does not match 'all'


PLAY [localhost] **********************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Use role in loop] ***************************************************************

TASK [role3 : debug] ******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "role3"
}

TASK [role4 : debug] ******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "role4"
}

TASK [role5 : debug] ******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "role5"
}

TASK [role6 : debug] ******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "role6"
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```